# unwanted indentation in console output

Tags: r, console

In rstudio when I run this code:
`cat(strrep("-", 5), "\n", strrep("-", 5))` 
The dashed line in the second row indented. How do I remove the indent?

I want this:
`-----`
`-----`

I get this:
`-----`
 `-----`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "indent" comes from a space that separates the entries of `cat()` so just add `sep=""` to the argument of `cat(...)`

```
cat(strrep("-", 5), "\n", strrep("-", 5),sep="")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy.

Comment: @AlexM You're welcome. Whenever a function gives you trouble,  just add `?` to the function name, i.e. `?cat` then run it, and you will see the documentation/manual for that function. This helped me a lot.